# Angular 6 library pipe

Tags: angular, pipe, angular6, angular-pipe, angular-library

How to add a custom pipe in an Angular 6 library in order for it to be available in my main app ? 
Currently I'm doing this in:
lib.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SomePipe
  ],
  exports: [
   SomePipe
]})
```

in public_api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/pipes/some.pipe';
```

in app.module.ts:

```
import { LibModule } from 'lib';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    LibModule
  ]
 ...
})
```

I'm trying to use the pipe `{{ 'something' | some}}` but `transform` method of `SomePipe` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom pipe was added correctly, and was working in my application. There was another bug that I did not manage to see, regarding a service *(imported incorrectly from the library)* that my @Pipe was using inside the transform() method. Therefore, transform() always appeared to return nothing, because it was relying on that service.

Answer (score 4):

So the issue appears to be here:

```
export * from './lib/pipes/some.pipe';
```

You are exporting everything from `some.pipe` file when you should have exported the module(`@NgModule`) from the module file. Something like this:

```
export * from './lib.module';
```

Doing that should fix the issue.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs1vbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Flib%2Findex.ts) for your ref.

Comment: The export export * from './lib/pipes/some.pipe'; is correct because my pipe implementation resides in some.pipe.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

you need go to module and import the pipe from this form:

```
import { SePipeModule } from 'se-component';
```

At this case, the "se-component" is the name of your "library" angular that you host the pipe, and the "SePipeModule" is the pipe module. Is very important that you export the name of pipe in "public-api.ts":

```
export {SeTestPipe} from './lib/se-pipe/se-test-pipe';
```